# Use Linq insted of Foreach (C#)

Tags: c#, function, linq, loops, foreach

I have got `foreach`:

```
public string myLookingValue;
...

foreach(var item in selected.Something)
{
  var check = item.Parameters.ToList();

  foreach(var lookingValue in check)
  {
     if(lookingValue.Value == "TEST")
       myLookingValue = lookingValue.Key;
  }
}
```

It's possible to don't run second `foreach`? Use just `Linq`?

Comment: Did you try `SelectMany`?

Comment: Performance could be increased by calling a 'break;' when you found the value you are looking for.

Comment: Why don’t you just write myLookingValue = „TEST“ ? Your loop seems useless to me.

Comment: Provide classes pls

Comment: like @Yuriy has do `item.Parameters .Where(lookingValue => lookingValue.Value == "TEST").ToList();` and then for loop that if needed basically change ur inner loop to filter with where instead of gong through every item and then checking.... i know its like the same same, but it terms of efficiency its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to assign `"TEST"` to `myLookingValue` if *at least one* of the `selected.Something.Parameters` equals to `"Test"`.

if it's your case

```
   using System.Linq; 

   ...

   myLookingValue = selected
     .SelectMany(item => item.Parameters)
     .Any(item => item.Value == "TEST") ? "TEST" : myLookingValue;
```

**Edit:** If you want to find out first `item.Value` which is equal to `"TEST"` and assign `item.Key` in this case:

```
   myLookingValue = selected
     .SelectMany(item => item.Parameters)
     .Where(item => item.Value == "TEST")
     .Select(item => item.Key)
     .DefaultIfEmpty(myLookingValue)
     .First();
```

Comment: how to insted of "Test" asign item.key ?

Comment: @4est: in this case you can try filtering (`WHERE`) and then either return (`First`) `item.Key` or `myLookingValue` if filtering return empty cursor

Comment: Thanks for quick turnaround

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will be the cleanest solution:

```
if (selected.Something.Any(item => item.Parameters.Any(param => param.value.Equals("TEST"))))
            myLookingValue = "TEST";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
item.Parameters
    .Where(lookingValue => lookingValue.Value == "TEST")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(lookingValue => myLookingValue = lookingValue.Value);
```

A. Your code is pretty readable as is, I wouldn't change it.

B. Why do you keep resetting the value of myLookingValue? Did you mean to do

```
myLookingValue = selected.Something
    .SelectMany(item => item.Paremeters)
    .Single(lookingValue => lookingValue.Value == "TEST").Value;
```

Comment: haha, thats cheating. Strictly speaking you are not "running second foreach" using linq...

Comment: `Single` will *throw exception* if we have *two or more* `"TEST"`; if we don't have `"TEST"` we'll have exception as well

Answer (score 0):

SelecteMany will do the trick for you.

```
selectedItem.SelectMany(obj=>obj.Parameters))
            .Foreach(param=>{do whatever you want to do})
```